# CSS styling not applying to jquery popup window

Tags: jquery, html, css, ruby-on-rails, popupwindow

I can't get my CSS styles to apply to a popup window in my Rails app. The popup window contains a bog-standard Rails form, a play button and a countdown timer using timer.jquery.js.

To test out timer.jquery.js, I wrote a similar html file. The styling there works just fine. There might be some obvious rule I'm missing for popup windows, but I've never worked with them before and there's nothing I've come across so far. Here's the test file that works fine:

**timer.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="timer.jquery.js"></script>
        <style>
            #timer {
                color: black;
                font-size: 50px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="timer"></div>
        <script>
            $('#timer').timer({
                format: '%H:%M:%S'
            });
            $('#timer').timer('pause');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And here are the relevant files I'm using in my Rails app:

**_track_time_form.html.erb**

```
<div id="countdown-timer"></div>
<div id="playback-controls">&#9658;</div>
<div id="track-time-form">
    <%= form_for @project, :url => { :action => "log_time" }, remote: true do |p| %>
        <ul>
            <li><%= p.label :project, "Project:"%><br>
            <%= p.collection_select(:id, current_user.projects, :id, :name) %></li>
            <%= p.hidden_field :time_logged, :value => 0 %> <!-- value set by script in log_time.js.erb -->
            <li><%= p.submit "Log time", id: "log-time-button" %></li>
        </ul>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

**track.js.erb**

```
timeTrackingForm = window.open("", "", "height=700,width=500");
$(timeTrackingForm.document.body).html("<%= j render( :partial => 'track_time_form' ) %>");

$(timeTrackingForm.document).ready(function(){
    var timer = $("#countdown-timer", $(timeTrackingForm.document))
    $(timer).timer({
        format: '%H:%M:%S'
    });
    $(timer).timer('pause');
});
```

**styling**

```
#countdown-timer {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
}

#playback-controls {
    font-size: 40px;
    color: black;
}
```

Comment: where you write this css?? in css file or in html itself?? i think your css code is not included. just verify it using firebug or other inspecting tool.

Comment: In custom.css.scss, which is where the rest of the styling for my app is located. The rest of the app's styling works fine.

Comment: i think this css is not get loaded in the popup. verify it by inspecting tools. loaded or not?? Try with writing your css in HTML page it self.

Comment: use `!important` in your css

Comment: You haven't included css file to you timer.html.

Comment: @GauravGupta it's in the style tags. There is no separate CSS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#timer').css({'color':'black','font-size':'50x'});
```

try adding the styling by js at the end of the page.

Comment: This does work, but I'd still rather include the styling in the regular ol' .css file as it seems a lot cleaner that way. Do you know the reason it's only this way that works?